# Adding constraint to two columns

Tags: oracle11g, constraints, database-table

I have a database table with columns `"User","Role"`and`"Application"`.
My requirement is that a user can only have one role but he can belong to multiple applications. I will want add this restriction in form of a constraint but i am not able to achieve it.

Setting unique constraint on "user" and "role" will not help. Also setting unique constraint on all 3 columns will also not help.

Can anyone suggest on how to set constraint here.

Edit1:

Following is the expected out:

```
User   Role   Application
U1     R1     A1
U1     R1     A2
U2     R2     A3
```

and so on... what i want to restrict is that now that U1 has been mapped to R1, U1 should not be mapped to any other Role.

Comment: how many applications that one user can relate to, i might ask?

Comment: At present not more than 6 but list can grow.

Comment: Are you allowed to create triggers on the table? Or fast-refreshable materialized views?

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to change your **table design** and **normalize** it further. If the **relationship** between `USER` and `ROLE` is `1-to-1` then have a lookup table for `user_role_mapping` and create another table for `user_application_mapping`.

Ideally your two tables would look like :

```
Create table user_role_map
   (
    user <datatype>,
    role <datatype>
    constraint user_pk primary key (user, role)
   );

Create table user_application_map
   (
    user         <datatype> NOT NULL,
    applications <datatype> NOT NULL
   );
```

Comment: Agreed but that option is not available.

Comment: Then simply have unique constraint on user and role. Simple!

Comment: That will not work, as i said a user with same role can belong to multiple apps, which would mean that user-role row will have to be repeated for each app.

Comment: You are confusing between the unique combination and repetition of the same combination. Can you post some example and show your desired output.

Comment: so you mean altering the schema is out of the option, and the answer's scope is only around this table only?

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Added sample output

Comment: @nobodykid: Exactly, i need to put a constraint only.

Comment: Are you allowed to create triggers on the table?

Comment: I insist, change your design first. Else, you would waste time on such things.

Comment: @nop77svk, don't forget the fact that triggers are always a side-effect. And in OP's case it would be even worse. OP must deal with the design issue first.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, yes, OP has issue with design. But he **clearly** stated that altering the data model is out of question, so I'm thinking about other options.